# how to initialize part of an array as zero c++

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I am a new programming student. I am currently studying pointers and dynamic arrays. The assignment I need help with asked me to create an array then use a function to double the elements and initialize the last half of the array as zeros. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void doubleArray(int*, int);

// Global variable for array elements
int numElems = 5;

int main()
{
 int* oldArray;    // Array variable
  oldArray = new int[numElems]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9};  // Makes the array dynamic

  // Display old array
  cout << "This is the old array.\n";
  for (int a = 0; a < numElems; a++)
  {
   cout << oldArray[a] << endl;   
  }

  // Double the array size, copy old array into new array, and initialize the rest of the space to zero
  doubleArray(oldArray, numElems);

  cout << endl;

  delete[] oldArray;
  oldArray = nullptr;

  return 0;
}

// Function doubles array size, copies old array into new array, and initializes the rest of the space to zero
void doubleArray(int* newArray, int size)
{
    size *= 2;
    for (int b = 5; b < (size/2); b++)
    {
       newArray[b] = {0}; 
    }
    cout << "This is the new array.\n";
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
    {
        cout << newArray[c] << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:
This is the old array.
1
3
5
7
9
This is the new array.
1
3
5
7
9
0
138433
0
0
0

As you can see, there is garbage in the second 'for' loop in the function doubleArray when it runs through the loop a second time. I have been diligently searching for an answer here on the forum, but have not yet succeeded.

Comment: should be `const int numElems = 5;`

Comment: The thing is you passed `oldArray` as the input `newArray`.  `oldArray` is old and still is only 5 int's long.  You have to make a new array that is twice the size.

Comment: There are many possible ways to do this,  before setting this assignment your class would have gone over some techniques that would be useful

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, they are very helpful. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The array you have allocated memory for is only for 5 integers , when you try to increase the number of elements you have to allocate more memory for the array.

What you should do is allocate memory for an array with double the size copy the contents of the initial array , and then assign the other half of the elements as 0.

And then return the reference of the new array or you could make the old array "point" to the new reference

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in `doubleArray` do you double the array. Instead you start stomping on the data around the old array. This is not a good idea. You don't know what's there. Could be something important. Could crash your program. In the old days it could have crashed the computer or smashed some important information in another program. Maybe someone's bank account. Maybe the instructions on where to fly the plane. Not good.

To fix this you will need to `new[]` yourself another array of `int`s twice the size of the original. Do not reuse the variable for the old array. If you write over it, you lose the old array. You still need to get the old data from the old array into the new array and if you don't put the old array away properly [you will leak memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Once you've done that, on to the next bit: preserving the old data and zeroing the rest of the new array. To do this, copy all of the data from the old array to the new array (a `for` loop is perfect for this job) and fill the remainder of the new array with zeros.

Next some house keeping. Since the old array is no longer needed, you can safely `delete[]` it to prevent the memory leak.

Finally return the new array to the caller.

If you're feeling brave, point out to your instructor that there's this really cool thing called [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that was invented back in the 1990s and basically does all this stuff (and a lot more!) for you.

Comment: Oh, okay that makes a lot more sense than what was going through my head. So now I just need to figure out how to take information from one array and put it in another. I will consult my text book and other questions on the site. Thanks so much for your help! :)